Adding nodes or Labels to a TikZ Cantor Set made with the decorate function
I have the following TikZ picture made with the decorate command
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=Cantor set,line width=2mm]
      \draw (0,0) -- (12,0);
      \draw decorate{ (0,-.5) -- (12,-.5) };
      \draw decorate{ decorate{ (0,-1) -- (12,-1) }};
      \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-1.5) -- (12,-1.5) }}};
      \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-2) -- (12,-2) }}}};
      \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-2.5) -- (12,-2.5) }}}}};
      \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-3) -- (12,-3) }}}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I would like to add labels I_n both at the end of each line and also I_{n,j} either next to or underneath a specific subinterval.
EDIT: When adding nodes underneath, how would I increase the distance between lines to fit them?

Welcome. // Please add the missing lines, which make your code compile. Without we have to guess about your preamble, which will lead to less and less useful answers. Please keep in mind, how complex, i.e. versatile, LaTeX is. Thank you

node [right] {$I_n$} at the end of the \draw right before the semicolon. You'd have to make the labels small or increase the distance to fit labels underneath, but you can do it with node [pos=0.5,below] {$I_{n,j}$} node [pos=0.7,below] ... node [right] {$I_n$}, for example, before the semicolon. Or use left or right etc. as you will.

This illustrates how to put nodes containing labels (1) at the end of the line, (2) beside a line segment (sub-interval?) and (3) below such a segment.
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=Cantor set,line width=2mm]
  \draw (0,0) -- (12,0) node [right] {$I_n$};
  \draw decorate{ (0,-.5) -- (12,-.5)node [pos=.35,right]  {$I_{n,j}$}  }node [right] {$I_n$};
  \draw decorate{ decorate{ (0,-1) -- (12,-1) }};
  \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-1.5) -- (12,-1.5) }}};
  \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-2) -- (12,-2) }}}};
  \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-2.5) -- (12,-2.5) }}}}};
  \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-3) -- (12,-3) node [pos=0.1,below] {$I_{n,j}$} }}}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

[Visual aids are currently on strike due to an Okular bug on X. Apologies for any disappointment this may occasion.]
